# Issue with Displaying Tenant Statistics in Citus Multi-Tenant Database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, multi-tenant, citus

I am experiencing an issue with my Citus multi-tenant database setup, where I am unable to retrieve expected tenant statistics. I am currently running Citus 12.1-1 on an Ubuntu server with a master node and four worker nodes. Below, I provide a detailed description of my setup, the operations I performed, and the issue I am encountering.

**Environment:**

- Citus Version: 12.1-1
- Host OS: Ubuntu (master and worker nodes)
- Number of Nodes: 1 master, 4 workers

1. Created two tables `companies` and `campaigns`, with `id` in `companies` and `company_id` in `campaigns` as distribution columns:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE companies (id BIGSERIAL, name TEXT);
   SELECT create_distributed_table('companies', 'id');

   CREATE TABLE campaigns (id BIGSERIAL, company_id BIGINT, name TEXT);
   SELECT create_distributed_table('campaigns', 'company_id');
   ```
2. Inserted data into these tables:

   ```sql
   -- Insert data into companies
   -- Insert data into campaigns
   ```
3. Executed various SELECT and UPDATE operations on these tables.

**Issue:**
When querying the `citus_stat_tenants` view to monitor tenant-related statistics, the expected output is not being displayed. The query used and its result are as follows:

```sql
SELECT tenant_attribute, read_count_in_this_period, query_count_in_this_period, cpu_usage_in_this_period
FROM citus_stat_tenants;
```

Expected Result:

```
tenant_attribute | read_count_in_this_period | query_count_in_this_period | cpu_usage_in_this_period
------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------
1                |                         1 |                          5 |                 0.000299
3                |                         0 |                          4 |                 0.000314
2                |                         1 |                          3 |                 0.000295
```

Actual Result:

```
tenant_attribute | read_count_in_this_period | query_count_in_this_period | cpu_usage_in_this_period
------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------
(0 rows)
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- Verified Citus version (12.1-1).
- Ensured that the tenant ID is correctly implemented and distributed.
- Restarted the PostgreSQL service and checked connections between nodes.
- Monitored for sufficient query activity.

I would appreciate any guidance or assistance you can provide to resolve this issue. Specifically, I am looking to understand why the `citus_stat_tenants` view is not displaying the expected tenant statistics and any steps I might take to troubleshoot or correct this.

Thanks.

Expected Result:

```
tenant_attribute | read_count_in_this_period | query_count_in_this_period | cpu_usage_in_this_period
------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------
1                |                         1 |                          5 |                 0.000299
3                |                         0 |                          4 |                 0.000314
2                |                         1 |                          3 |                 0.000295
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that you need to set the `citus.stat_tenants_track` to `"all"` in all your nodes to be able to track the statistics.
You can put the setting in the `postgresql.conf` file to be able track the all `citus.stat_tenants_track`, but it dose not work with me, so I execute this function in the terminal and it worked.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET citus.stat_tenants_track TO 'all';
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: ALTER SYSTEM SET citus.stat_tenants_track TO 'all';                                                          SELECT pg_reload_conf();